# what is class member named Void .ctor() in c# . this is appear when i use GetMethods

Tags: c#, reflection, types

when i use GetType on Class,  Void .ctor() is appear on DeclareMembers.

but this class has no member named Void .ctor().

what is  Void .ctor()?

Comment: The constructor of the class. You can get it with `GetConstructors()`

Comment: It is a default constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the constructor of the class (in this case a parameterless constructor). You can get it with `Type.GetConstructors()`. If you find a `.cctor` then it is the static constructor of the class.